# unable to detect request content_type

Tags: python, django, python-requests

On a django server, I process uploaded zip files sent from a python script.  But I am getting "" (a blank string) for file.content_type.  What am I doing wrong?

```
@csrf_exempt
def Import( request ):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed('Only POST here')

    if not request.FILES or not request.FILES.get( u'file' ):
        return HttpResponse('Must upload a file')
    file = request.FILES[u'file']
    if file.content_type == 'application/zip':
        unzipped_dir = unzip_file( file )

        uid = create_project( unzipped_dir )

        shutil.rmtree( unzipped_dir )
        py_ob = { }
        py_ob['success'] = uid is not None
        if uid is not None:
            py_ob['id'] = uid
        json_ob = simplejson.dumps(py_ob)
        return HttpResponse( json_ob, mimetype="application/json" )
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed( 'Only POST zip files here' )
```

This is the script which sends the zip file up:

```
import sys
import os
import requests

if len (sys.argv) < 5:
    print "pass in url, username, password, file"
else:

    url = sys.argv[1]
    username = sys.argv[2]
    password = sys.argv[3]
    phile = sys.argv[4]
    if os.path.exists(phile):
        files = {'file': open( phile, 'rb' )}
        r = requests.post( url, files=files, auth=( username, password ) )
        if r.status_code == 200:
            json_response = r.json()
            if json_response['success']:
                print "id: " + str( json_response['id'] )
            else:
                print "failure in processing bundle"
        else:
            print "server problem: " + str(r.status_code)
            print r.text
    else:
        print "cannot find file to upload"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content-Type header is [completely arbitrary](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload#Using_.E2.80.9CContent-Type.E2.80.9D_from_the_Header) (and optional) and not a good way to detect whether or not you're dealing with a valid ZIP file. Have you made sure your browser is supplying it?

[Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploadedfile-objects) tells us the same:

> **UploadedFile.content_type**
>   *The content-type header uploaded with the file (e.g. text/plain or application/pdf). Like any data supplied by the user, you shouldn’t
>   trust that the uploaded file is actually this type. You’ll still need
>   to validate that the file contains the content that the content-type
>   header claims – “trust but verify.”*

You should be using [`zipfile.is_zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.is_zipfile) instead.

Comment: Thanks -- your answer led me to this snippet which handles is_zipfile for file_pointers.  https://github.com/pculture/django-uploadtemplate/blob/master/uploadtemplate/utils.py#L58